# How to check whether a value in a list is a numeric type?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list 'vals' which is in the format [age,income,gender] I want to find out whether age and income are encoded as numeric types

```
vals = [[37, 48701.413701616024, 'f'], [57, 55559.77744809075, 'f'], [21, 44217.05520426258, 'm'], [64, 57313.15824195174, 'm'], [31, 48504.05753555914, 'f'], [77, 57761.55864292855, 'f'], [58, 54295.161011633056, 'm']]
```

I tried to use the .dtypes method but it obviously didn't work as this isn't a dataframe, so I'm struggling to find the correct method.

Comment: Do you want this: `pd.DataFrame(vals).dtypes`

Comment: You can use `isinstance(value, type)` to check if a value has that type.

Comment: What output do you expect ?
For your example : `True` if all entries are OK ?

Comment: You can use the `numbers` module as an abstract base class, e.g. `isinstance(value, numbers.Number)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that gives you a boolean list that could be used to help you select or mask values that meet your criteria. Based on your example data, I assume you only have ints and floats.

```
vals = [
    [37, 48701.413701616024, "f"],
    [57, 55559.77744809075, "f"],
    [21, 44217.05520426258, "m"],
    [64, 57313.15824195174, "m"],
    [31, 48504.05753555914, "f"],
    [77, 57761.55864292855, "f"],
    [58, 54295.161011633056, "m"],
]
numeric_types = (int, float)
boolean_mask = [
    (isinstance(x[0], numeric_types) and isinstance(x[1], numeric_types)) for x in vals
]
print(boolean_mask)
```

outputs:

```
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```